# How to toggle Premiere Pro Scripts in Adobe CEP toggle Play / Pause of the current sequence?

Tags: scripting, jsx, complex-event-processing, adobe-premiere

I'm trying to control Adobe Premiere Pro remotely by using an Adobe CEP Panel and then interacting with a server using websockets. Everything works fine, however, I cannot find any API to play / pause the current sequence.

There is one available for the SourceMonitor (https://premiere-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/general/sourcemonitor.html#sourcemonitor-play) but I want to play the sequence.

I also would like to control the lumetri color panel and the audio mixing faders. I cannot find any APIs for those either. Is there a better approach for doing that?

My backend is a NodeJS application by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it by using QE DOM manipulation on the JSX side.
I recommend you checking this unofficial PPro CEP doc.
https://vidjuheffex.github.io/ppro.api/

There is a `startPlayback()` method.
don't forget to call
`app.enableQE()` before.

Your code should look like this

```
app.enableQE()
qe.startPlayback()
```

Comment: I believe [this](https://ppro-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/index.html) documentation is more updated than the one you mentioned. It still outdated but it was the best I could find

Comment: for some reasons the official doc that you believe is more updated are missing some key features. It seems devs at Adobe dont care that much about CEP. you wont find anything regarding triggering "master" playback on it where the unofficial I linked provide more useful informations. I know it's strange. I wrote them once to ask why they were "hiding" such informations and got a bad answer too.

Comment: here is the topic I opened on their forum:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/cep-ppro-how-to-get-transport-playback-state/m-p/11866478#M332157

Comment: the maintainer stated that there were no way to do it. hopefully after research I found  this unofficial doc which is proving the opposite :/